# Replace string in file with string from different file

Tags: string, sed, replace

I would like to store a series of strings in a text file that will be used for replacing strings in other files.

Background is that I write a bash script, but want to have more flexibility with the text file, so that you don't have to constantly adjust the script.

Example:

```
FILE_A.txt
active_name = "THE COMPANY";
```

This is the file where the string needs to be replace

```
FILE_B.txt
active_name = "THE USER";
```

I would like to search for "**active_name =**" in FILE_A.txt but replace only the string in the quotation marks, only with the content in the quotation marks from FILE_B.txt.

Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: Seems like a pretty common thing to want to do with Unix tools but it's a job for awk, not for sed. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you need then [edit] your question to provide a btter example that includes cases this doesn't work for:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS= 'NR==FNR{new=$2; next} {$2=FS new FS} 1' FILE_B.txt FILE_A.txt
active_name = "THE USER";
```